# how to use HTML onselect without violating CSP?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So what I'm trying to do is when someone select an element of **'select'** form, does something that has been defined on "showPost()" function on script section. and CSP is keep rejecting my operation :(

I've tried both CSP hash and CSP nonce. and both doesn't work.

If I apply **'unsafe inline'** it works, so the function has no problem.

What should be wrong?

**P.S.** : I'm using custom CSS style inside the HTML(EJS) file, so I did CSP hash work on that too on CSP styleSrc setup. and it works just fine.

### 1. Error Message

[image: error image]

### 2. My Select Form

[image: image of select from]

### 3. Code

##### Part of HTML(EJS) File

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Order of Aboutme" id="aboutmeOrder" onchange="showPost()">
                <option selected>글 순서를 정해주세요..</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>

....
....
  <script nonce="example">
  function showPost(){
    var select = document.getElementById("aboutmeOrder").value;
    console.log(select);
  }
  </script>
```

##### Part of index.js FIle

```
const csp = require('helmet-csp');

app.use(helmet());
app.use(
    csp({
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        styleSrc: ["'self' 'sha256-uts7zrnGYAKZNfvBc7PYcShvKP4t10vo5qemd5Yp0lc=' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/"],
        scriptSrc: [`'self' 'sha256-RemzkHuAMqaMxa/UriyGSEioInZdZJpm6lnkGuugweU=' 'nonce-example' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/`],
      },
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

nvm, I've got the answer

you have to use 'unsafe-hashes' or gotta use js file.

https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-hashes/